# Why does final image output appears black, even though "Blender Render" window renders fine? (Blender 3.0)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

While rendering, the "Blender Render" window shows exactly what I would expect from a Cycles Render. Nothing wrong here:

[image]

However after the render is done for each frame, it suddenly outputs a black screen:

[image]

As i was rendering an animation, these were the .jpg output for frames 105,106,107 and 108 which overwritten the previous files that worked:

[image]

The problem is, i didn't take note what properties i changed and i didn't save the file with the previous render settings that worked. These are my current render settings in the "Render Properties" tab:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Can you check compositing? You may be using compositing activated and no nodes plugged to the output node.

Comment: For not having saved the file with the previous settings: I don't know if you are aware of the *.blend1 backup files. When you save a file, Blender creates a second file with the *.blend1 extension where the previous version is saved. In the Open dialog box you can set the filter to also show these files. Of course this doesn't help if you've saved the not working version more than once. But Blender can keep more than one old version, you can change it in the _Preferences_ > _Save & Load_ > _Save Versions_, the default is 1 (was 2 some time ago) but you can set it up to 32 versions.

Comment: Just a stupid question on my behalf: did you accidentally set the lights to only be visible in Viewport, but invisible in Render? I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, are now all frames black or only 105 - 108?

Comment: This question is closed, because it supposedly has answers elsewhere already, but I don't believe this is the case. This question is different, as I've just ran into the exact same issue. Rendering was running fine in my case, but the final result turned black because the denoiser for the render was enabled, but not properly configured (empty drop down box?). Disabling the denoiser fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Check the render visibility of your objects. There is a difference between something being made invisible in the viewport and something being made invisible in the render. If you make something invisible in the viewport, you might forget that it's even still there.

Go to your outliner and have a look. If something lacks an eyeball or computer monitor symbol but has a camera symbol, it's visible in render but not in the viewport.

By default, you'll need to enable the icon for viewport visibility in the Outliner, but render visibility is enabled. You can use the menus at the top of the Outliner for this.

Comment: By "default" the render visibility **is** enabled in the Outliner. Or did you mean it's "required" for an object to be rendered?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for the heads up, my mistake. I meant viewport visibility. Answer has been edited to clarify and correct.

Comment: I still wonder if there are just a few frames black or all of them, because if it's only a few then either the visibilty is also animated or there is some other reason for that. I would really appreciate if people asking questions would come back here to answer comments for clarification...